# How do I disable CakePHP rewrite routing for a single folder so it can be used as a location for a second application?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have a cakephp installation in the root of my domain. Now it turns out I need to put another app in there that will reside in a subdirectory. How do I disable the controller/model redirection in cake for just this directory?

The current .htaccess in the root folder looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried modifying it like this, but to no avail:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^bildbank$ /bildbank/ [L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am aware that this is a bit of a hack, but there's no way I can get the second app to play nice with cake.

Comment: Did you try to put the second app to app/webroot/bildbank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following rule rewrites www.example.com and www.example.com/ to www.example.com/app/webroot/

```
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
```

This rule rewrites www.example.com/* to www.example.com/app/webroot/*

```
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

I would throw out your rule and update the wildcard regex in the last rule, `(.*)`, so that it matches any string which doesn't start with `bildbank`. Something like this might do the trick:

```
RewriteRule    ((?!bildbank).*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

This converts the following strings:

```
cake
cake.htm
cake/test
bilder
bilder.htm
bilder/test
bildbank
bildbank.htm
bildbank/test
```

.. into:

```
app/webroot/cake
app/webroot/cake.htm
app/webroot/cake/test
app/webroot/bilder
app/webroot/bilder.htm
app/webroot/bilder/test
bildbank
bildbank.htm
bildbank/test
```

.. therefore, excluding your `bildbank` subdirectory.

Answer (score 12):

Deizel's answer didn't work for me, but placing the following RewriteRule above the two cakephp rules did:

```
RewriteRule ^bildbank - [L]
```

Comment: Deizel's answer didn't work for me neither, but this did. Using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: Working in my case.  +1

Comment: working...! write this code immediately after RewriteEngine on